# SQL: Group by in subquery

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, subquery

I'm trying to find the output of all books that have more than one genre using a group by statement and subquery. However, it keeps returning `Subquery returns more than 1 row`. This is what I have so far:

```
SELECT title 
  FROM book 
 WHERE 1 < (SELECT COUNT(genre) FROM genres GROUP BY book_id);
```

Comment: Update your quetion add  a proper data sample and the expected  result

Comment: Have you tried to run your inner query by itself, and see if it returns more than 1 row or not?  If it is, then you found your problem.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

`SELECT distinct a.title
  FROM book a, (select bookid,count(distinct genre)genres  from genres group by bookid)b
 WHERE a.book_id=b.bookid and b.genres>1`

hope it helps!

Comment: Learn to use proper `JOIN`.  It's been around for over 25 years.

Comment: Thanks Eric, preferred single character than typing 4. On a serious note, does it have impact in performance?

Answer (score 3):

Here's an example:

```
SELECT b.title
  FROM ( SELECT g.book_id
           FROM genres g
          GROUP 
             BY g.book_id
         HAVING COUNT(1) > 1
       ) m
  JOIN book b
    ON b.id = m.book_id
```

The inline view `m` is meant to return us values of `book_id` that appear more than one time in the `genres` table. Depending on uniqueness constraints, we might want to count distinct values of `genre`

```
         HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT g.genre) > 1
```

if we want to find books with exactly three related genre:

```
         HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT g.genre) = 3
```

Once we have a list of `book_id` values, we can join to the `book` table. (The query assumes that `book_id` in `genres` is a foreign key reference to the `id` column in `book` table.)

Answer (score 1):

You seem to what a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT b.title 
FROM book b
WHERE 1 < (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM genres g WHERE g.book_id = b.book_id);
```

Comment: this is a workable approach. correlated subqueries can get expensive for large sets, when the outer query returns a lot of rows. +10

Comment: @spencer7593 . . . The performance should be fine, particularly with an index on `genres(book_id))`.